# Split string on the left in C++

Tags: c++, string, split

I'm trying to write a short and stupid equation parser, and need to split a string around a given operator. I can split off the right side of a string by doing

```
return std::string(oprtr + 1, equ.end());
```

where equ is the string, and oprtr is an iterator for the position I need to split from. Doing this works perfectly, but splitting off the left, however, doesn't:

```
return std::string(equ.begin(), oprtr - 1);
====
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
```

I've tried a variety of other nasty workarounds that I'm really not proud of, like

```
return equ.substr(0, std::distance(equ.begin(), oprtr));
```

This one doesn't give errors, but actually just returns the entire equation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not enough code to figure it out. What's oprtr?

Comment: oprtr is an iterator to the position I need to split from. Sorry, I'll add it to the question text.

Comment: `return std::string(equ.begin(), oprtr);` and `return std::string(oprtr + 1, equ.end());` look correct to me. Not sure why you want to substract one from your end position.

Comment: Need to subtract one from the end position because I don't want the operator itself included. In any case, the `return std::string(equ.begin(), oprtr);` is the main one that I'd like to use, but still throws the above mentioned error.

Comment: @Sourec You don't need to substract one to not include the operator. Need to read up on iterator ranges I think. string(i, j) creates a string starting at i up to **but not including** j.

Comment: @Sourec Need more code I think

Comment: @VisualMicro std::string does not use a zero terminator

Comment: @john Err, crap, not what I meant. Seriously my bad there, was thinking of something totally different. You're right, don't need to include the -1, not sure what I was thinking. Thanks! Still doesn't solve the original issue, but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are doing something like this

```
void my_func(string equ, string::iterator oprtr)
{
    string left = std::string(equ.begin(), oprtr);
}

string::iterator oprtr = equ.find('=');
my_func(equ, oprtr);
```

That won't work because in `my_func` you have two iterators to different strings. Because the original string is copied when you call `my_func`.

One fix is to pass by reference

```
void my_func(string& equ, string::iterator oprtr)
```

Another fix is to use integers instead of iterators. Integers aren't tied to one particular string instance like iterators are.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I don't know how I missed that, I guess it just didn't cross my mind because splitting to the right worked fine using the same technique. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Works for me with `g++ 4.8.2`:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::string eq("a+b=c");

    std::string::iterator opit = std::find(eq.begin(),eq.end(),'=');

    std::string lhs = std::string(eq.begin(),opit);

    std::cout << "lhs: " << lhs << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:
`lhs: a+b`

Comment: So that works for me too, but it uses the exact same thing I tried earlier, doing the splice with the constructor... yet somehow this works without throwing an error. I must assume that it has something to do with std::find(), but unfortunately that's not applicable to my case, the entire thing is actually in a function, with the iterator and the string passed in as arguments.

Comment: So that's the clue, you are passing an iteration and a **copy** of the string that the iterator points to. You need the original string, not a copy. Pass by reference.

Comment: @Sourec You should really post a minimal working example which demonstrates the error. Okay, john's hint is true. If you pass `std::string` you will get a copy but the iterator is for the original string. You should pass the original string with the argument type `std::string&`.